# How do you use a behavioral resistor in pySpice?

Tags: python, pyspice

I am trying to simulate a very simple circuit with behavioral resistors that change state based on a global parameter. Really I'm just new to *spice and playing with "resistors as switches"

The working circuit in ngspice is:

```
.param pos = 1

vin 1 0 dc 10
r1 1 2 r='{pos} == 1 ? 1u : 1G'
r2 2 0 1
r3 1 3 r='{pos} == 2 ? 1u : 1G'
r4 3 0 1
```

Which when run (and 'pos' is altered) does exactly what I expect:

```
Circuit: resistor switch circuit

Doing analysis at TEMP = 27.000000 and TNOM = 27.000000

No. of Data Rows : 1
v(2) = 9.999990e+00
v(3) = 1.000000e-08
Reset re-loads circuit resistor switch circuit

Circuit: resistor switch circuit

Doing analysis at TEMP = 27.000000 and TNOM = 27.000000

No. of Data Rows : 1
v(2) = 1.000000e-08
v(3) = 9.999990e+00
```

I'd like to recreate this circuit in pyspice which looks like this:

```
circuit = Circuit('resistor switch circuit')
circuit._parameters['pos'] = 1
circuit.V('input', 'in', circuit.gnd, 10@u_V)
circuit.R(1, 'in', 'pos1', raw_spice='r=\'{pos} == 1 ? 1u : 1G\'')
circuit.R(2, 'pos1', circuit.gnd, 1@u_Ohm)
circuit.R(3, 'in', 'pos2', raw_spice='r=\'{pos} == 2 ? 1u : 1G\'')
circuit.R(4, 'pos2', circuit.gnd, 1@u_Ohm)

print(circuit)
```

And generates a netlist that as far as I can tell is (effectively) the same as the ngspice netlist above:

```
.title resistor switch circuit
.param pos=1

Vinput in 0 10V
R1 in pos1 r='{pos} == 1 ? 1u : 1G'
R2 pos1 0 1
R3 in pos2 r='{pos} == 2 ? 1u : 1G'
R4 pos2 0 1
```

However running it results in the following:

```
2023-01-10 17:01:07,739 - PySpice.Spice.NgSpice.Shared.NgSpiceShared - Shared.ERROR - Original line no.: 4, new internal line no.: 5:
2023-01-10 17:01:07,739 - PySpice.Spice.NgSpice.Shared.NgSpiceShared - Shared.ERROR - Syntax error: letter [{]
2023-01-10 17:01:07,739 - PySpice.Spice.NgSpice.Shared.NgSpiceShared - Shared.ERROR - Original line no.: 4, new internal line no.: 5:
2023-01-10 17:01:07,739 - PySpice.Spice.NgSpice.Shared.NgSpiceShared - Shared.ERROR - Expression err: {pos}==1?1u:1g}
2023-01-10 17:01:07,739 - PySpice.Spice.NgSpice.Shared.NgSpiceShared - Shared.ERROR - Original line no.: 4, new internal line no.: 5:
2023-01-10 17:01:07,739 - PySpice.Spice.NgSpice.Shared.NgSpiceShared - Shared.ERROR - Cannot compute substitute
2023-01-10 17:01:07,740 - PySpice.Spice.NgSpice.Shared.NgSpiceShared - Shared.ERROR - Original line no.: 6, new internal line no.: 7:
2023-01-10 17:01:07,740 - PySpice.Spice.NgSpice.Shared.NgSpiceShared - Shared.ERROR - Syntax error: letter [{]
2023-01-10 17:01:07,740 - PySpice.Spice.NgSpice.Shared.NgSpiceShared - Shared.ERROR - Original line no.: 6, new internal line no.: 7:
2023-01-10 17:01:07,740 - PySpice.Spice.NgSpice.Shared.NgSpiceShared - Shared.ERROR - Expression err: {pos}==2?1u:1g}
2023-01-10 17:01:07,740 - PySpice.Spice.NgSpice.Shared.NgSpiceShared - Shared.ERROR - Original line no.: 6, new internal line no.: 7:
2023-01-10 17:01:07,740 - PySpice.Spice.NgSpice.Shared.NgSpiceShared - Shared.ERROR - Cannot compute substitute
```

I believe pyspice supports behavioral resistors:
https://pyspice.fabrice-salvaire.fr/releases/v1.3/api/PySpice/Spice/BasicElement.html#PySpice.Spice.BasicElement.BehavioralResistor

But regardless of how I try to provide the expression:

```
circuit.R(1, 'in', 'pos1', '{pos} == 1 ? 1u : 1G')
circuit.R(1, 'in', 'pos1', R='{pos} == 1 ? 1u : 1G')
```

and so on I always get some kind of error when trying to run the simulation. Only "raw_spice=" seems to truly give a compatible netlist - but then fails at the simulation.

How do you actually use a behavioral resistor in pyspice?

Comment: The first error appears to be a syntax error related to the `{` character -- what is the correct syntax?

Comment: Well, that was it - what's odd is that ngspice itself takes {pos} just fine and works exactly as expected. I had seen multiple other posts using {} around params/variables so that's what I used. But it seems regardless of how you give it to pyspice it's trying to do some kind of translation or for some other reason gets tripped up. It's valid in ngspice directly loading the netlist with it in there.

Regardless, knowing that it will work without it, I can at least move forward. Thanks for planting the seed that {} might not be required.

Comment: if you figured out a solution to your problem, care to post it as a self-answer for [future reference](https://xkcd.com/979/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per Joshua's comment - including {} around a variable/parameter name (as with {pos} in my examples) seems to not be required for proper parsing.

Oddly, ngspice directly readily accepts that format. Being new to using netlists I saw that format used quite frequently in sample code, and since it worked, presumed it was required to denote vars/params - it is not.

Removing the extraneous '{}' from the component creation (though I am still passing the equation in via raw_spice) resolves the issue and lets the simulation run. Answering here for future reference.